# WebDriverError - missing 'type' parameter

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am getting the following error:

```
[23:31:47] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[23:31:47] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://seleniumbox.cisco.com:80/wd/hub
[23:31:51] E/runner - Unable to start a WebDriver session.
[23:31:51] E/launcher - Error: WebDriverError: Missing 'type' parameter
```

I have the following Protractor config:

```
 multiCapabilities: [

    {
      browserName: 'firefox',
      auth: 'qn4gn6i63h3bo25i',
      firefoxOptions: {
        auth: 'qn4gn6i63h3bo25i',
        args: ['--headless']
      },
      'moz:firefoxOptions': {
        auth: 'qn4gn6i63h3bo25i',
        args: ['--headless']
      }
    }
]
```

I think the "type parameter" might relate the auth method, because before I add the auth information (I had to auth in multiple places because I don't know the right place...), I was getting this error:

```
[23:35:38] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[23:35:38] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://seleniumbox.cisco.com:80/wd/hub
[23:35:38] E/launcher - Mandatory capability missing[auth]
[23:35:38] E/launcher - SessionNotCreatedError: Mandatory capability missing[auth]
```

Does anyone know if this type parameter relates to auth? How do I fix this error?

Comment: What is the purpose of having "auth" in multi-capabilities?

Comment: I am connecting to a remote selenium server that requires authentication

Comment: Haven't tested, but maybe this answers https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/selenium-users/6l8nTdKsBLw/OepHTz4dy_kJ

Comment: Can you open this url `http://seleniumbox.cisco.com:80/wd/hub` in browser without any proxy setting in browser?  And when you open it,  there will be auth prompt  to ask you input username and password?  And tell me you try above on windows on linux machine?

Comment: Looked the `New Session` WebDriver Sepcification at W3C: https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#new-session, in  the `EXAMPLE 6` mentioned auth information, And Looked into the Protractor source code, have not found valueable information how to pass the auth information as top-level paramter along with capabilities. Just give you some direction when you do research.